# Choosing between virtual function, function_pointer and functors

Tags: c++, virtual, functor, boost-function

I am writing a class in which a one of the function's implementation depends on the users. Currently I have it as a virtual function and users need to override my class to provide its implementation. I am thinking of making it a functor(boost::function)/function_pointer so that users can register to it.
Application is extremely performance critical and speed is more important than the classes looking nice. Is changing to functors give some performance benefit?

In most cases, it will be a free function so a function pointer should be fine. But I guess there would be some cases where state may be required and hence it needs to be a functor.

Will I get any preformance benefit by allowing to register either a function_ptr or a functor and calling the appropriate one based on some bool? Something similar to this.

```
class Myclass
{
   public:
    registerFuncPtr(FuncPtrSignature);
    registerFunctor(boost::function func);
   private:    
   someMethod(someArgs)
   {
    ...
    if(_isFuncPtr)
        _func_ptr(args);
    else
        _functor(args);
    ...
   }
   bool _isFuncPtr;
   FuncptrSignature _func_ptr;
   boost::function _functor;
}
```

**Update:**

I am writing a shared library and the clients would dynamically link against it. 
No C++0x. :(

Comment: @x4d33: Lambdas would be used in client code, not here.

Comment: @x4d33: That is just non-sense, one of those lines that you read from somewhere and blindly apply everywhere... As with templated code, it will be more efficient in those circumstances where it can be used, but if the extensions are to be added after compilation of the product, then you would have to apply *type erasure* to the lambda to be able to use it in a pre packaged solution, and that can make it more costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after performance, go with naked function pointers. If you need state, provide a separate state argument of type `void*` in your function, and let the users register their state. There's no magic that can make any C++ construct to be faster than that, since functors and virtual functions and all the rest are all just function pointers wrapped in a more or less type-safe envelope.

More importantly, when talking about optimization, you should no trust anything whatsoever but your profiler (this includes the paragraph above BTW).

Inlining could in theory improve the performance, but the users' functions cannot be inlined (a compiler cannot inline code that hasn't been written yet). If you don't compile your library, but distribute it as source code, there's a possibility of some performance benefit due to inlining. As always, only a profiler can tell.

One case when a function object is likely to outperform a function pointer is passing them to a function template. If the template itself is not getting inlined, then the function object is likely to get inlined inside the template instantiation, and the function pointer is not.

Comment: The cpp core guidelines specifically say to prefer functors over function pointers for better performance. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#-t40-use-function-objects-to-pass-operations-to-algorithms

Comment: @djhaskin987 The quidelines say that without any explanation. I don't see how this could possibly hold with inline functions. When passing an inline function, the compiler can always behave as if it's getting an empty function object instead. No new optimisation opportuninies arise.

Comment: @n-m  I appreciate the insight. I would be interested to see any benchmarks or graphs on this topic, if you know of any. You have a point; I should see some data before I take the CppGuidelines as truth, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is true, as it was written by very smart people. (As an aside, the lines stating functors were faster were written by Andrew Pardoe, a Microsoft engineer. https://twitter.com/apardoe )

Comment: @djhaskin987 I think I understand in which cases a functor can outperform a function pointer. If the calling function is a template but it's not getting inlined, then it may be able to inine a functor but not a function pointer. But this is more a limitation of current compilers than anything else.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on your particular use case and how the users add their code. The following is a purely theoretical analysis, but you should build a realistic scenario and test the performance before actually deciding.

If the code is to be added at compile time (i.e. you provide the code to the users, they create their logic and compile everything together) then probably the best approach is to provide a template that takes a `Functor` type argument.

```
template <typename Functor> void doProcessing( Functor f) {
   f( data ); 
}
```

The advantage is that the compiler has access to the whole code, and that means that it can take the best decisions as to whether it inlines or not the code, and might be able to optimize further in the case of inlining. The disadvantage is that you need to recompile the program with each new piece of logic and that you have to compile together your product with the user extensions, with many times it not possible.

If the extensions are to be performed *after* compilation of your main product, i.e. clients can produce their own extensions and use them to a compiled executable (think plugins) then you should consider the alternatives:

- accept a function pointer (the C way)
- provide an interface (base class) with just that operation (the Java way)
- use a functor wrapper (`boost::function`/`std::function`) that performs type erasure

These are ordered by pure performance. The cost of the C way is the smaller of the three, but the difference with the interface option is negligible in most cases (an extra indirection per function call) and it buys you the option of keeping state in the calling object (this would have to be done through global state in the first option).

The third option is the most generic as it applies *type-erasure* to the user *callable*, and will allow users to *reuse* their existing code by using function adaptors like `boost::bind` or `std::bind` as well as lambdas if the compiler supports them. This is the most generic and leaves the most choices to the user. There is an associated cost to it though: there is a virtual dispatch in the type erasure plus an additional function call to the actual piece of code.

Note that if the user will have to write a function to adapt your interface with their code, the cost of that manually crafted adaptor will most probably be equivalent, so if they need the genericity, then `boost::function`/`std::function` are the way to go.

As of the difference in costs of the alternatives, they are most probably *very* small overall, and whether scratching one or two operations matters will depend on how tight the loop is and how expensive the user code is. If the user code is going to take a couple hundred instructions, there is probably no point in not using the most generic solution. If the loop is run a few thousand times per second, scratching a few instructions will not make a difference either. Go back, write a *realistic* scenario and test, and while testing be aware of what really matters to the user. Scratching a few seconds of an operation that takes minutes is not worth loosing the flexibility of the higher level solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am ready to provide two different overloads for function pointer and functor (as shown). Will that be any better than just going with a functor alone (as functor allows functionptrs also)?

Comment: +1 for sane reasoning! Just one note: even though functors are usually passed by copy in the STL this need not be the case. Using an overloaded by reference/by const reference pair might be better if the functors are expected to carry a lot of state.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can and easily inlines Functor calls rather than calls to functions through function pointers So yes prefer a Functor over function pointer.

Comment: And, as usual, the only sure way to know is to measure.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: I agree, but most likely, functors *will be* faster than function pointers, the Q is how much faster, and that would matter if one was trying to replace code using function pointers with functors, to know if the performance benefit is worth the effort. Since in this case the OP intends to write the code afresh, it makes sense to just use Functors.

Comment: @Als that does not need to be true, and as a matter of fact chances are that it will be the exact opposite (i.e. if user code is to be added dynamically)

Comment: In my case, I will be giving out a shared library to link against. Will in-lining work in this case too?

Comment: Since this is a library, can the compiler inline functor calls of functors that don't even exist yet?

Comment: @balki: No, inlining is a compile time (sometimes link time) optimization, and cannot be performed after the program is built.